# How to show the article details , i m facing problem

Tags: reactjs, api

I am trying to show details of the article and I am facing a problem When I click on the article to see details its shows nothing so please help me out from this problem

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';


class Details extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);

    this.state = {
        question: null,
      };
}

async componentDidMount() {
    const { match: { params } } = this.props;
    const question = (await axios.get(`http://trivago-magazine-work-sample-server.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/latest_posts.json/${params.id}`)).data;
    console.log(question)
    this.setState({
        question
    });
  }


//   }

render() {
    const {question} = this.state;

    if (question === null) return <p>Loading ...</p>;
    return (
        <div>
           <h1> Hello </h1> {question.title}
        </div>
    )
  }
}

 export default Details
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJJO2.png)

Comment: Is the issue just that you're getting that 404 error from your request? It looks like the endpoint you're using doesn't accept an id at the end. If you use the url without an id, you'll get valid data.

Comment: http://trivago-magazine-work-sample-server.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/latest_posts.json/{id} is not a valid route I think.Without the `/{id}` it returns all. Where are the docs for this API?